# Issues in loading gems from env.rb file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, appium

I have 2 env.rb file(for desktop browser and mobile browsers) which has all the required environment related setups done.

The below line is present in both env.rb files but it does not work when included in one of the file(mobile browser). These are the standard gems used.

```
require 'time_diff'
require 'rubyXL'
require 'Prawn'
```

All though the files are exactly the same except including few more external libraries, we get the below error when running the Appium script.

```
cannot load such file -- time-diff (LoadError)
```

Any idea where to look for the problem?

***EDIT:***

The difference in both the files are below. Apart from these lines, other lines are related to normal variable assignment and config file handling.

**File 1:**

```
$LOAD_PATH<< File.expand_path('../features/DesktopWeb/pages', 'common.rb')
```

**File 2:**

```
$LOAD_PATH<< File.expand_path('../features/MobileWeb/pages', 'common.rb')
```

Comment: I have a feeling you have `require time-diff` not `require time_diff` (notice underscore vs hyphen)

Comment: The issue occurs even for RubyXL gem and Prawn too. All works fine when included in desktop version of env.rb file.

Comment: More code will be required to determine the issue then.

Comment: Have edited the question to show the file difference.Could not show more code as it's restricted as per policy of my organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue and i tried the below steps that resolved my issue.

Add all gems in Gemfile.

```
require 'time_diff',
require 'rubyXL',
require 'Prawn',
```

run  "gem install bundler" this will install the bundler.

run "bundle install" from the project directory where the Gemfile is placed.

This will install all the gems and there dependency gems. 
Then try to run your code...

Hope this will resolve your issue.